# MarkLogic: fn.empty fn.exsits !== null !== ""

Tags: conditional-statements, marklogic

What is the ultimate difference among below statement in order to determine if cts.search returns a valid document?

```
1. if (!fn.empty(acctDoc)) {....}
    2. if (!fn.exists(acctDoc)) {....}
    3. if (acctDoc !== null || acctDoc !== "") {...}
```

My experience is that No.3 works in every aspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `if (!fn.empty(acctDoc)) {....}` Return true if the `acctDoc` ***is not* an empty sequence**.
2. `if (!fn.exists(acctDoc)) {....}` Return true if `acctDoc` **is an empty sequence**.
3. `if (acctDoc !== null || acctDoc !== "") {...}` Return true if the `acctDoc` is not `null` or if it is not an empty string.

[fn.empty()](https://docs.marklogic.com/fn.empty)

> If the value of $arg is the empty sequence, the function returns true; otherwise, the function returns false.

[fn.exists()](https://docs.marklogic.com/fn.exists)

> If the value of $arg is not the empty sequence, the function returns true; otherwise, the function returns false.

Using this test function:

```
function test(acctDoc) {
  const results = [];
  if (!fn.empty(acctDoc)) { results.push("not empty") };
  if (!fn.exists(acctDoc)) { results.push("does not exist") };
  if (acctDoc !== null || acctDoc !== "") { results.push("not null or is not empty string") };
  return results;
```

}

- `test("test")` returns `["not empty", "not null or is not empty string"]`
- `test("")` returns `["not empty", "not null or is not empty string"]`
- `test(null)` returns `["does not exist", "not null or is not empty string"]`
- `test(fn.head(fn.doc()))` returns  `["not empty", "not null or is not empty string"]`
- `test(fn.doc(fn.string(xdmp.random())))` returns `["does not exist", "not null or is not empty string"]`

Comment: When evaluating `assetDoc != ""` it seems that even an empty result is evaluating to an empty string when comparing. `fn.exists` and `fn.empty` are basically the same thing, just opposite of each other. Whatever reads cleaner for you, but I would use `fn.exists()` to avoid negating `!fn.empty()`.